# Nextcloud (via Docker) - Input/output error

Tags: docker, docker-compose, raspberry-pi4, nextcloud

i created a `docker-compose.yml` file to be prepaired for the day i want to setup a nextcloud instance via docker (compose).

The day passed and everything worked as it should - nextcloud and the database container worked smooth und i started using nextcloud.

Some quick notes focussing my setup: 
I used a Raspi4 with 8GB of RAM. I pluged a SSD into the PIs USB3 port and mapped that unser `/mnt/ssd` (on startup via fstab). The idea was to store all volumes on that external drive to get more disk space. I use the nextcloud image (not the nextcloud-fpm image). To serve nextcloud i use the nginxproxymanager.

At this point everything worked quite perfekt.

A few days after the setup i wanted to test if everything works if i suddenly unplug the power supply (of my raspi). The idea was to simulate a power failure.

After rebooting the pi i started my containers - obviously :P.
BUT nextcloud doesnt want to work anymore - the DB seems to work properly (according to the logs) but if i call the url i assigned to nextcloud - nextcloud loads until death.
The death of nextcloud results in a `reading directory '.': Input/output error` error.

At this point nothing works anymore.
I tried to restart the containers multiple times - also a `docker compose up -d --force-recreate` doesnt help.

Tried solutions:

- i tired this with 2 of the 3 possible DBs nextcloud supports (`mysql` and `postgres`) same behaviour every time.
- i also changed the OS from `raspberry pi os (lite 64Bit)` to `ubuntu 22` - same error

Note:
i tried the same procedure (create - remove power - reconnect power - continue using) with several other docker containers (=program setups) like `nginxproxymanager`, `authelia`, `vaultwarden` and many more - none of these programs showed any type of issue after rebooting the Pi.

Does anyone have an idea what im doing wrong?

For testing:
i have the same issue if i use the docker compose example on dockerhub - it doesnt matter if i use the `mysql` or the `postgres` example

Comment: That generally means there's a hardware failure: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39905/input-output-error-when-accessing-a-directory

Comment: thats correct but if i remove the nextcloud container(s) the others work as expected so that has to be something else - a hardware failure is only the result of whatever kind of error that is